# Help Identify this Lego Item/Set

Tags: set-identification

The photo is from December 30,1991.
Colors are red, yellow,
black, green and white. It was a Christmas gift for our 10 year old.
[image]

Comment: I remember those tootsie roll containers from those days.  Fun times.  :)

Answer (score 8):

That would be:
[6956: Stellar Recon Voyager](https://brickset.com/sets/6956-1/Stellar-Recon-Voyager)

[image]